# Jquery: why .val() isn't changing the output when setting something inside as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to insert some text from an input box into a div on the click of a button.
So, what's inside the **#horario09** div, should be replaced by "**La reserva es para: '+nombre**" where nombre is whatever you've inserted into the text input.

```
<form id="form1" action="">
        Horario: 09 horas <input type="text" id="h09">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return reservas.guardarReserva();">Reservar</button>
        <div id="#horario09"></div>
</form> 

var reservasAPP = {
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var nombre = $('#h09').val();
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').val('La reserva es para: '+nombre);
        console.log(nombre);
        console.log(reservaConfirmada);
        return false;
    }
}
window.reservas = reservasAPP;
```

I'm inserting some console.log() in order to test, and nombre gets printed ok. Why [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) isn't replacing the div's content? I've read the documentation and it seems that it should change the value when I set something as a paratemer of val().

Console.log of reservaConfirmada gets me this output:
**[context: document, selector: "#horario09"]**

Comment: your return is object not string. return object ´#horario09´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<div id="#horario09"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="horario09"></div>
```

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

Use .[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)() instead

Answer (score 6):

You are replacing text in div. For div use

```
$('#horario09').text();//if you enter text
$('#horario09').html();//if you enter html
```

.val() is for inputs.

Comment: Yep, `$('#horario09').text('La reserva es para: '+nombre);` to be exact

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the div as :

```
<div id="horario09"></div>
```

Instead of :

```
<div id="#horario09"></div>
```

And then try :

```
var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').html('La reserva es para: '+nombre);
```

OR

```
var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').text('La reserva es para: '+nombre);
```